# where should i put image in spring web application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am creating spring  a web application using maven in eclipse and project structure is

similar to `http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/spring-mvc-gradle-folder.png`

so i think i should put images under resources folder i.e under main folder.

Now if i am putting my image there i am not able to access it through the code- `<img alt="" src="natedimages/pipe.jpg">`

i have created a folder natedimages under resources.

Please suggest some solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static web resources go into src/main/webapp.

This is as opposed to everything src/main/java and src/main/resources, which will end up on the Java classpath.

Comment: But for maven project in eclipse then what is use of resource folder ?

Comment: Of the `src/main/resources` folder? You put stuff that is needed on the Java classpath but that should not be downloadable, such as `applicationContext.xml` or `.properties`. That wasn't the original question, though.